# Why did Maester Luwin want Bran and Rickon to be taken to the wall in S02E10 of GoT

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In S02E10 of Game of Thrones, after the men from the Greyjoy army stab Maester Luwin and flee, Bran & Rickon with Osha and Hodor come to Maester Luwin.

Why does Luwin want them to go to the wall and meet up with Jon? The Stark's allied forces were on their way. There was no Greyjoy army. So why didn't he want them to just wait outside the castle (castle was on fire) in someone's home till they come rather then sending them on a dangerous path to the wall. What was the danger for Bran and Rickon to stay at Winterfell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Winterfell sacked it was no longer safe. The Greyjoys could have easily returned, or other enemies of the Starks might attack. Bran is also (at the time) Robb's only heir and had to be protected, so it was safer for them to go to the Wall. The Starks have always been an ancient ally to the Night Watch, and Jon Snow was there as well. They could easily find shelter there.

Late season 3 spoilers:

> Maester Luwin's fears proved to be true. The Boltons took advantage of the situation to overthrow their liege lords the Starks.

Comment: You might want to add why it's safe to to to the Wall.  That Jon and the Nightswatch would protect them.

Comment: I realize this is an old question, but it should be pointed out that it was not the Ironborn who burned Winterfell - it was the Bolton host lead by Ramsey. We're shown a scene of Theon being knocked out and the Ironborn about to surrender to the host outside the gates. In the next Winterfell scene the castle is shown burning. Theon is also in Ramsey's custody. Roose then lies to Robb, blaming Theon for burning the castle and informing him that his whereabouts are unknown. Luwin probably saw the deception, which is why he thinks the boys will be safer at the Wall than in allied hands.